# Plugin shortcode displays the template page in page editor (admin panel) Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am  creating a plugin for wordpress themes that loads the templates in its own directory rather than placing templates in the theme that makes me independent to include templates in themes, for that I have created shortcodes to load the different templates on conditions. below is the code:

> add_shortcode('template', 'add_template');
>
> function add_template( $atts) {
>              extract( shortcode_atts( array(
>                 'template' => ''
>                ), $atts         )   );
>
> switch ($template) {
>
> ```
>   case 'template1':
>     include 'templates/template1.php';        
>     break;
>
>   case 'template2':
>     include 'templates/template2.php';            
>      break;
>
>   default:
>     include 'templates/template1.php';        
>      break;   
>    }  
> }
> ```

My problem is in some themes my plugin start to display the page within the admin panel is there anything I am doing wrong? please help....

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution we just need to add a check that the user is not admin before including template.

```
add_shortcode('template', 'add_template');

function add_template( $atts) {
extract( shortcode_atts( array( 'template' => ''
), $atts ) );

switch ($template) {

  case 'template1':
     if ( !is_admin() ) {
         include 'templates/template1.php';
     }
     break;

  case 'template2':
       if ( !is_admin() ) {
        include 'templates/template2.php';
       }            
       break;

  default:
     if ( !is_admin() ) {
       include 'templates/template1.php';
     }        
     break;   
   }  
}
```